# Layered Navigation in home page Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, layered-navigation, home-page

I need add layered navigation to home page.

I see in many sites and [Tutorial](https://www.manadev.com/documentation/magento-2-guides/price-slider-for-layered-navigation/layered-navigation-on-home-page-or-any-cms-page)  that I have to add in `Content->Pages` in home this line:

```
<update handle="cms_page_layered_navigation_with_product_list" />
```

But It not works for me.

It is configuration in Content->Pages->home:

[image]

And this is the frontend page:

[image]

Why?

Comment: Share what have you tried and have you tried updated layout of page to 2col left ?

Comment: I modify the post

Comment: I meant by code of that cms page...  Specifically design section of it

Comment: @AndresF Have you solved this?